# Trying to get Jquery working with dynamic select forms in Rails and Active Admin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to update a select box based on another..

In my active admin resource, I did the following just for some test data:

```
controller do

  def getcols
    list = new Hash
    list = {"OPTION1" => "OPTION1", "OPTION2" => "OPTION2"}
    list.to_json
  end
end
```

In active_admin.js I have the following

```
$('#worksheet_type').change(function() {

  $.post("/admin/getmanifestcols/", { ws_type: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
            populateDropdown($("#column_0"), data);
        });
});

function populateDropdown(select, data) {
 select.html('');
    alert('hi');
    $.each(data, function(id, option) {
       select.append($('<option></option>').val(option.value).html(option.name));
    });       
 }
```

The above is working in the sense that when my primary select box is changed, the jquery is called and I even get the alert box of 'hi' to be called. However, it's not replacing the contents of the select box with my test OPTION1 and OPTION2 data.

I think I'm passing in the JSON wrong or something, or it's not being read.

What am i missing?

Comment: it would be faster to have controller render a partial and then the populateDropdown will append the return html, rather than having the JS and browser memory do all the work.

Comment: also use console.log(data) within the populateDropdown function to read the javascript object you are returning in your browsers console.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you're not properly iterating over the map.

What about:

```
$.each(data, function(value, name) {
   select.append($('<option></option>').val(value).html(name));
});
```

?